# SQL Server trigger gets EXECUTE permission when calling sp_start_job

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I checked the rights and SQLAgentUserRole and it has EXECUTE GRANT, what is the typical way to fix this?  A web page causes an insert which fires the trigger and from the trigger I try to call the SQL Server job. I can run the `EXEC` from the SQL prompt perfectly.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'myJob'
```

The exact message is:

> Service Error: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_start_job', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The typical way to fix permission problems is to grant the required permissions. To be able to do so, you need to know what login or database user needs to be permitted. Do you know this? Do you mind letting us know? How is authentication configured? What permissions / role memberships have you set?

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang I'm tasked to add a job that gets started from a trigger, this trigger on INSERT fires when the webpage calls a 3rd party webservice, the DB was setup by somebody else. I have the sa pwd. There about 6 DBs and the standard msdb, master etc.  need this job to be started from a trigger in one of the DBs tried to call a store proc in the trigger but that was failing & not advisable and people recommended to do a sp_start_job which got me into this. I granted execute rights to targetServerRoles and that gave me cannot find the job which is supposed to be another rights issue.

Comment: You should rethink your trigger - since a trigger is executed in the context of the statement that caused it to fire, that statement won't complete until the trigger is done. Therefore, the trigger should be **very small, fast, and nimble** - you should **NOT** be doing any heavy lifting / intense processing inside a trigger - and calling a SQL Server job sure sounds like a time consuming operation - **don't do this!** You need to rearchitect your solution so that the trigger **doesn't need** to call that job ...

Comment: >>>I checked the rights<<< Who's permissions did you check? Your trigger is executed under the user who odes INSERT